# Reading MySQL manuals in MySQL monitor?

Tags: mysql, manual

**Problem:** To read MySQL's manual effectively

**Error:**

```
mysql> create database plastronics
    -> ;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'plastronics'; database exists
mysql>
```

**Question:** How do I check it quickly like in [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29): ":h 1007"?

[The introduction material I was reading](http://code.google.com/edu/tools101/mysql.html#Audience)

Comment: Please, pay attention more to the content of your next questio. Tip: Less is More.

Comment: @Masi: Thank you. It should be now better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to your problem**

1. Make a Vim-like K button for MySQL in Screen.
   Note that it is not possible to put all manuals under K.

**Practical solution**

1. Download MySQL manuals to your computer. *(not sure whether Sun gives zip-files of them)*
2. make a binding `Ctrl-A Esc Ctrl-m` for instance for **M**ysql's manuals in .screenrc

Please, search/read Screen's manual for more info by

```
man screen
```

or by pinfo

```
pinfo screen
```

Comment: I opened a new question about the problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082966/to-have-vim-like-k-in-screen-for-mysql

Answer (score 4):

A [list of error messages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html) is available on the MySQL website. However, it isn't really going to help you if the error the server spit out didn't.

You asked MySQL to create a database; MySQL replied that it can't create that database because it already exists. You can't have two databases on the same server with the same name. You need to either pick a different name (e.g., `create database plastronics2`) or drop the already-existing database (`drop database plastronics`).

Please beware that dropping a database destroys everything in it (tables, views, procedures, all the data, etc.)

Looking at the tutorial you linked, it appears it shows the same create database statement twice in a row. I suspect you just entered the statement twice, instead of once as the tutorial's author intended.