# PHP database and Acquia Drupal loaded on Macbook Pro

Tags: drupal

I hope this is not a dumb questions. I have the apache Web server and MySql database server stack installed on my MacBook Pro. I would like to uninstall this from my laptop along with DRUPAL 7, but I don't see an uninstall for the full stack.

Thanks for your help....

Ron

Answer (score 1):

How to uninstall the "full stack" depends greatly on how it was installed as there are many options.

Here are answers with lots of assumptions on how you installed.

**Drupal 7:**
Delete the root directory of Drupal, most likely at ~/sites/
From the terminal - sudo rm -Rf ~/sites/

Delete the Drupal 7 database.
From the terminal:
mysql -u root; mysql> drop database ;
ref: [How do I remove a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082130/how-to-remove-mysql-database)

**Stopping MySQL:**
Answered here - [How do you stop MySQL on a Mac OS install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-you-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install)

**Stopping Apache:**
In Lion, do the following:
To turn on Apache, go to System Preferences > Sharing and *disable* Web Sharing.
ref: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083

Later versions, do the following:
From the terminal:
sudo killall httpd
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
ref: https://superuser.com/questions/486966/can-i-end-all-httpd-processes-osx-10-7-4-lion