# To have Vim-like K in Screen for MySQL

Tags: mysql, gnu-screen, manual

This question is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081399/reading-mysql-manuals-in-mysql-monitor).

**Problem:** to access MySQL's manual when the cursor is at the beginning of the word by

```
Ctrl-A Esc Ctrl-m
```

where m reminds about **M**ysql.

**How can you build a Vim-like K in Screen for MySQL's manuals?**

Comment: I opened a thread about installing MySQL manuals at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104536/unable-to-install-mysql-manuals-to-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've installed the man pages from [MySQL's documentation site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/):

Put the following in `/path/to/mysql-help.screen`:

```
# mysql-help.screen

# prevent messages from slowing this down
msgminwait 0
# copy term starting at cursor
copy
stuff " e "
# write term to a file
writebuf /tmp/screen-copied-term
# open that file in man in a new screen window
# (use `read` to pause on error, so user can see error message)
screen /bin/sh -c 'man `cat /tmp/screen-copied-term` || read'
# turn message waiting back on
msgminwait 1

# vi: ft=screen
```

Then add this to your `~/.screenrc`

```
# Have CTRL-A ESC put you in a mode to accept commands in the 'escaped' class
bind \033 command -c escaped
# add CTRL-M as an 'escaped' class command to run the given screen script
bind -c escaped ^M source /path/to/mysql-help.screen
```

Then your keybinding should work.  If you're using a different program to display
the manual other than `man`, you'll have to change the script accordingly.

The `man` pages for mysql that I found at the link above only include documentation
for the following commands:

> `mysqlbug` `mysqlhotcopy` `perror` `mysqldump` `resolveip` `mysqltest_embedded` `mysql_setpermission` `mysql_client_test` `mysql_find_rows` `mysql_fix_privilege_tables` `mysql_waitpid` `mysql_config` `mysql_client_test_embedded` `myisampack` `replace` `msql2mysql` `make_win_bin_dist` `my_print_defaults` `mysql`-`stress`-`test`.`pl` `mysqlaccess` `mysql_secure_installation` `mysql`.`server` `mysql_convert_table_format` `mysql_zap` `mysql_fix_extensions` `myisamlog` `myisam_ftdump` `mysqlbinlog` `mysql_install_db` `resolve_stack_dump` `mysqlslap` `mysql`-`test`-`run`.`pl` `mysqld_safe` `mysqladmin` `mysqlshow` `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` `mysqltest` `mysqlbackup` `mysqld_multi` `mysql` `mysqldumpslow` `mysqlcheck` `mysql_upgrade` `mysqlimport` `comp_err` `mysqld` `myisamchk` `innochecksum`

You may also want to consider adding

```
zombie kr
```

to your `.screenrc`, so that if you run the manual on a term that it doesn't recognize, screen doesn't automatically close the window (and hide the error message).

Comment: @rampion: There seems to be a bug in the binding commnad ` bind -c ... -c escpaped`. I tried to fix it unsuccessfully by `bindkey -m ^m source /Users/masi/bin/screen/mysql-help.screen`.

Comment: @rampion: Which Screen do you use? I use 4.00.03 (OS X) and it does not seem to have the defzombie -command.

Comment: well, you misspelled escaped.  and it's two commands , which is why it's on two lines.

Comment: try zombie rather than defzombie, then.

Comment: (Also using that same screen - didn't realize that defzombie wasn't supported)

Comment: Did you install the manpages correctly?  Pick a directory from your $MANPATH and put all the `.1` files in the `man1` subdirectory and the `mysqld.8` file in a `man8` subdirectory.

Comment: @rampion: Thank you for your last answer! - I have now manuals correctly installed. --- I suggests the following improvement to the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082966/to-have-vim-like-k-in-screen-for-mysql/1117061#1117061

Comment: @Rabion: A new question about the bug is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120438/to-fix-a-bug-in-vim-like-k-in-screen-for-manuals

Comment: @rambion: please, see this question about your codes at github http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120756/unable-to-understand-a-code-in-screenrc

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure how to start you off creating a wrapper for vim to do exactly what you want, I might make a suggestion on how you can achieve a similar effect with a function built into vim.

`:! <command>` will allow you to run shell commands with a similar interface to vim's K command. It might not be the cleanest way to do it, but by using `:!` you should be able to call the MySQL manuals for a given term quickly without completely leaving vim.

If you really need to write your own plugin for vim, [this article](http://items.sjbach.com/97/writing-a-vim-plugin) might be able to give you some pointers and a handhold on where to start.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is to build such an component to Screen such that you can use those manuals everywhere where you MySQL error messages in terminal. --- To build such an component to Vim would make us editor-dependent which is not a good thing.

Comment: Ah, you're not looking to build a plugin for vim, you want to build a plugin for Screen. Sorry, that wasn't quite clear.

Comment: I also started writing a mapping for Vim before I realized that it needed to be for Screen instead.

Answer (score 0):

I love to recycle my Man -pages such that I can read easily manuals.
I suggests the following improvement to Rampion's command.

**Rampion**

```
screen /bin/sh -c 'man `cat /tmp/screen-copied-term` || read'
```

**Me**

```
screen /bin/sh -c 'man `cat /tmp/screen-copied-term` > /tmp/manual | less /tmp/manual'
```

[My code gives you the percent sign to the bottom of a manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049350/unable-to-make-less-to-indicate-location-in-percentage).

Comment: @rampion: Please, see this thread about your command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120756/unable-to-understand-a-code-in-screenrc