# Unable to install MySQL manuals to Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, manuals

This question is based on [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082966/to-have-vim-like-k-in-screen-for-mysql/1104350#1104350).

I downloaded the manuals as the file "v5.1 (Maria) TGZ".
I moved the file to `/usr/share/man/`. I could not access the manuals by

```
man mysqlbug
```

The .tar.gz -file has these files which do not include README

```
comp_err.1
innochecksum.1
make_win_bin_dist.1
msql2mysql.1
my_print_defaults.1
myisam_ftdump.1
myisamchk.1
myisamlog.1
myisampack.1
mysql.1
mysql.server.1
mysql_config.1
mysql_convert_table_format.1
mysql_find_rows.1
mysql_fix_extensions.1
mysql_fix_privilege_tables.1
mysql_install_db.1
mysql_secure_installation.1
mysql_setpermission.1
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql.1
mysql_upgrade.1
mysql_waitpid.1
mysql_zap.1
mysqlaccess.1
mysqladmin.1
mysqlbinlog.1
mysqlbug.1
mysqlcheck.1
mysqld.8
mysqld_multi.1
mysqld_safe.1
mysqldump.1
mysqldumpslow.1
mysqlhotcopy.1
mysqlimport.1
mysqlmanager.8
mysqlshow.1
mysqlslap.1
perror.1
replace.1
resolve_stack_dump.1
resolveip.1
```

---

I copied the files to /usr/share/man/mysql.
However, I could not access the manual by the keyword `mysql`.

**Where should I put the files such that I can access them by Man?**

**How can you install MySQL manuals to OS X Leopard?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .1 suffix indicates the files go in section 1 of the manual. You'll need to make sure you move the files to /usr/share/man/man1 and that /usr/share/man is in your MANPATH environment variable (it should be already).

Answer (score 1):

The ".tgz" means that these files are archived with tar and compressed with gzip.  You should be able to open up the file with `tar xvfz` and then the filename.  Bear in mind that there may be multiple files, I don't know if they're in man format, and I don't know the directory structure.  I'd do it in a working directory, not `/usr/share/man`, just to see what it actually is.

Alternately, there are likely instructions where you downloaded the file.

Comment: @David: Please, see my edit. The extension of files is ".1". Are the files in man -format? The content at least seem to be ASCII-color codes in the files.

Comment: I'm not at a place I can check right now, but I think that's probably man format.

Answer (score 1):

As `man man` explains in detail, `man` can access single compressed files (so it's OK to gzip one or more individual manpages and name them with a `.gz` suffix) but cannot look inside archives of pages, and a `tar` (gzipped or not) is exactly such an archive.  So you need to unpack it, as @David mentions (you might then gzip each individual page, if you're desperate to save disk space).