# What does || mean in .screenrc?

Tags: gnu-screen

Command based on **[Rampion's command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082966/to-have-vim-like-k-in-screen-for-mysql/1104350#1104350)**

```
screen /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/man `cat "$@"` > /tmp/manual | less /tmp/manual || read'
```

`|| read` does not mean *or* in the command. `read` seems to be a built-in -command about which I did not find explanation in my OS X's manuals.

**What does `||` mean in the command?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`||` is nearly 'or' operator.

In the code example above it will first run  `less /tmp/manual` and if it returns a value that is not true it will run `read`. If the first command returns a true value then the read command is not performed because of short circuiting.

*Thanks to [Michiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120338/michiel-buddingh)*: please note that the operator is not commutative such that it is not mathematical OR.

Comment: @MitMaro This is a nitpick, but the behaviour you describe is not equivalent to a logical or.  A real 'or' is commutative, i.e. (a \/ b) = (b \/ a).

Comment: @Michiel: Your point is excellent! - I was confused because my both commands are successful but only the first one is run. --- This suggests me that I can remove the last part of my code.

Answer (score 3):

What MitMaro said. It's a parameter for the shell, or /bin/sh in this case. (Technically it's not a "parameter" (that's a different term) but it's part of the shell's "grammar.")

For details, you can read the [man page on sh](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sh.1.html). What you're looking for is under the "Lists" section.

Snippet:

> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if and only if command1 returns a non-zero 
>   exit status.
>
> The  return  status  of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last 
>   command executed in the list.

Comment: I never knew where in the man pages to look for this. Thanks GreenReign.