# Unable to understand a code in .screenrc

Tags: gnu-screen

I am not sure about the exact purpose of the following [Rampion's code](http://gist.github.com/139318).
It should apparently execute command(s) at the cursor position.

```
# man-word.screen

# prevent messages from slowing this down
msgminwait 0

# copy word starting at cursor
copy                         # I am not sure why we need this
stuff " e "

# open a new window that waits for a word to run man on
# (and uses 'read' to pause on error)
screen -t man /bin/sh -c 'cat | xargs man || read'       # option -c seems to mean execute

# feed that window the copied word
# be sure to enter '^M' as 'CTRL-V ENTER' and '^D' as 'CTRL-V CTRL-D' (in vim)
paste '.'
# should display as 'stuff "^M^D"'
stuff " "

# turn message waiting back on
msgminwait 1

# vi: ft=screen
```

The code is bound under `^g` such that

```
bindkey -m ^f source /Users/masi/bin/screen/edit-file-under-cursor.screen
```

which is same as

```
bind f source /Users/masi/bin/screen/edit-file-under-cursor.screen
```

I run the code as my cursor is at the beginning of the following line

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

I get a new buffer such that

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-rampion.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-rampion.png)

**What is the purpose of the command**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the command doesn't run arbitrary code.  All it does is run `man <whatever>` in a new screen window if your cursor was over the word `<whatever>`.

The reason the `copy` command is there is that you need to tell screen that you want to copy something.  You may not always be in screen's copy mode when over a path - for example, you could be using vim, and have vim's cursor over a path.  If you are already in copy mode, then it's a no-op.

```
screen -t man /bin/sh -c 'cat | xargs man || read'
```

- `screen` :: open a new window
- `-t man` :: give it a title of `man`
- `/bin/sh -c 'cat | xargs man || read'` :: run this command in the new window, rather than opening the default shell in the new window.

  - `/bin/sh` :: a shell program
  - `-c 'cat | xargs man || read'` :: run the given string as a script, rather than opening in interactive mode
  - `cat |` :: wait for user input (ended with a newline and a CTRL-D), then pipe it as user input to the next command
  - `xargs man` :: call `man`, using whatever's read from standard input as command line arguments for `man`
  - `|| read` :: if the previous commands return non-zero, wait for the user to hit enter

From your output it looks like

1. The `-c` part of the command isn't getting run, since it looks like a new shell (the `$` is a hint).
2. The `stuff "^M^D"` part wasn't transcribed correctly.  The next non-comment line after `paste '.'` should be entered, keystroke for keystroke, as :

   ```
   's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'f', ' ', '"', <CTRL-V>, <ENTER>, <CTRL-V>, <CTRL-D>, '"'
   ```

If you had [downloaded the file](http://gist.github.com/gists/139318/download), rather than transcribed it, you may not have those issues.

Also, `bindkey -m ^f` is not the same as `bind f`.  And neither bind a command to `^g`.

- `bindkey -m ^f` binds a command to `<CTRL-f>`, but only when in copy mode.
- `bind f` binds a command to `<CTRL-A> f`, in all modes.

Comment: Do you mean that if you use the command always in Screen's copy-mode, you do not need the command `copy`? --- I have always used such commands in Screen's copy-mode only. *What is the main benefit of using such commands outside Screen's copy-mode?* --- *How can you do that?*

Comment: Well, the cursor isn't always at the end of txt outside of copy mode.  In vim, when using readline, etc, the cursor can point to various text.  So I chose to make my commands able to work directly in those cases, without having to switch to copy mode first.

Comment: @rampion: I opened a new thread about `xargs` at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121776/to-understand-xargs-better

Comment: I need the command `xargs man` b/c I'm feeding the copied text in through a paste.  So I need the command I run in the new screen window to wait for me to paste some text in, and not run before that.  xargs waits on a user input, and makes it into a command line argument for me.  Without xargs, screen would just run `man` (no arguments), which wouldn't be very helpful.