# To understand recursive grep in xargs

Tags: grep, xargs

What is the practical difference between the following two commands?

**Command A**

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -r masi
```

**Command B**

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep masi
```

In short, **what is the practical benefit of Command A?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None .. `-r` is for recursively searching directories, but the `-type f` will prevent `find` from returning directory names.

Answer (score 1):

I think none
The A will try to recurse over file names (as the find is only searching for files) so it will not recurse into anything...