# How can you search only filenames by find?

Tags: find

This question is based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121807/to-understand-recursive-grep-in-xargs/1121817#1121817).

I run at home

```
find -- ./ Desktop
```

I understand the command as

1. find without parameters
   at the current directory that is home (= /Users/masi/)
2. find the folder name Desktop at the current directory

**How do you read the command?**

Comment: Did you mean `./Desktop` rather than `./ Desktop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
find ./ -name Desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question in the title is

```
$ find . -type f
```

Now, keep in mind that

```
$ find -- ./ Desktop
```

will return the files in `Desktop` twice.

Comment: You seem to be right. --- I have though `find` as `find <option> <folder> <filename>`.

Comment: * I mean with filename folderName too.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, "`--`" says to stop looking for further options. Everything else after that is a path, so it finds anything else matching that. And since "`./`" means "the current directory" it matches everything under the current directory (the `Desktop` will cause that directory, as well as anything inside it, to be reported twice.)

You probably want something like:

```
find ./Desktop -type f
```

Which will find any files inside the ./Desktop directory, that is a file (not directories, symbolic links, etc...)

I know that manpages can be quite technical sometimes, but "`man find`" will give you a wealth of other options that might help, as well as a few examples that may help with common problems.

Comment: I now know what my confusion was. `-type` is not an single-letter-option, but instead a many-letter-option that is called `expression` in find's manual of OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can pass multiple directories to search to find:

```
$ find --help
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
[...]
```

Note the "[path...]" indicating you can specify multiple paths.

So your example will find all files and directories under ./ (current dir) *and* under Desktop.