# To understand the practical use of Grep's option -H in different situations

Tags: grep

This question is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121776/to-understand-xargs-better/1121897#1121897).

**Why do you get the same output from the both commands?**

**Command A**

```
$sudo grep muel *                                                             /tmp
masi:muel
```

**Command B**

```
$sudo grep -H muel *                                                          /tmp
masi:muel
```

Rob's comment suggests me that *Command A* should not give me `masi:`, but only `muel`.

In short, **what is the practical purpose of `-H`?**

Comment: Are you going to go through each and every option of every *nix command line utility? Just wondering ...

Comment: It's not QUITE at the level of "what does -H do", more "in what situation might you use it". Not a great question title, admittedly.

Comment: @Bobby Jack However, see http://stackoverflow.com/users/54964?tab=recent#sort-top

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Grep will list the filenames by default if more than one filename is given.  The `-H` option makes it do that even if only one filename is given.  In both your examples, more than one filename is given.

Here's a better example:

```
$ grep Richie notes.txt
Richie wears glasses.

$ grep -H Richie notes.txt
notes.txt:Richie wears glasses.
```

It's more useful when you're giving it a wildcard for an unknown number of files, and you always want the filenames printed even if the wildcard only matches one file.

Comment: @Richie: Bobby's answer is excellent. I did not know before about the practical implications of the option.

Answer (score 6):

If you grep a single file, -H makes a difference:

```
$ grep muel mesi
muel

$ grep -H muel mesi
masi:muel
```

This could be significant in various scripting contexts. For example, a script (or a non-trivial piped series of commands) might not be aware of how many files it's actually dealing with: one, or many.

Comment: Could you give an example where it is useful to use the option `-H`, please. I have never needed it before.

Comment: If you pipe, grep will read from standard input. That means no file names.

Comment: Hmm.. tricky off the top of my head. I can imagine a script that 'walks' through a bunch of directories, collecting file names from each that a given term appears in, passing the results of 'grep' to cut. -H would guarantee filenames, even if only a single file was searched in the first place. That's not a GREAT example, but it's a specific as I can be at short notice! :)

Comment: @Zr40: good point, although I guess I was thinking more of the output FROM grep being piped elsewhere (see other comment)

Comment: Working with `xargs` is one place; if there's just one file sent to it, then the `grep` will not print the file name unless you either tell it to (GNU `grep -H`, but not POSIX `grep`) or unless you use '`xargs grep whatever /dev/null`' so that `grep` always sees at least two file names (actually, if it is given no names, `xargs` still runs `grep something /dev/null`, but that produces no output - probably what was wanted anyway). You can also get this effect if `xargs` processes files in batches of 20, and you have 41 files in total. It is exasperating not to see the last file name!

Comment: @Jonathan: How can you show that it is exasperating to see the last filename? --- I would like to feel that.

Comment: @Masi: suppose you've just run a 'find' operation over a 200 GB disk drive, and it took an hour and a half to do the grepping. You got one file with results - but 'grep' didn't show you the file name because it was the very last file looked at, and it was the only file in the command list produced by 'xargs'. You now know that the data exists in a file - but you don't now which one; you've got to redo that entire 'find' command again (maybe not the 'xargs' and 'grep', so it will be quicker, but ...). That would be frustrating to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you grep from multiple files, by default it shows the name of the file where the match was found. If you specify -H, the file name will always be shown, even if you grep from a single file. You can specify -h to never show the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has grep interface (M-x grep, M-x lgrep, M-x rgrep). If you ask Emacs to search for foo in the current directory, then Emacs calls grep and process the grep output and then present you with results with clickable links. Clickable links, just like Google.

What Emacs does is that it passes two options to grep: -n (show line number) and -H (show filenames even if only one file. the point is consistency) and then turn the output into clickable links.

In general, consistency is good for being a good API, but consistency conflicts with DWIM.

When you directly use grep, you want DWIM, so you don't pass -H.